# Scapy ConditionalField Help

Tags: python, packet, scapy

I need help with the ConditionalField in Scapy. I am having trouble with the lambda function, how can I get the lambda function to check for a specific layer in the packet?

At present I have the code

```
lamda pkt: pkt.haslayer(RTP) == 1
```

This doesnt appear to work, I dont think pkt contains the contents of the pkt, how can I get around this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Knowing what "doesn't work" means in this case would be helpful. Do you get an error, or is it simply not filtering what you expected? I wrote an answer assuming the latter.

Comment: I cannot find out how to access the methods/attributes of the whole packet. I dont get an error as such, it just doesnt dissect correctly. If I could just identify how to access the full packet contents I could solve the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `lambda pkt: pkt.haslayer(RTP)`. My guess is that `haslayer()` returns something that is seen by Python as `True` but is not equal to 1, so your comparison to 1 is always returning `False`.